# Can we leverage browsers' "text-search" feature in an HTML5 app?

Tags: api, html, full-text-search, sencha-touch

We are working on a HTML5 app feature that does exactly like the 'text search' feature in a browser: highlighting the targeted texts.

We are wondering, since browsers already have this feature, can we just leverage its ability and call the feature directly from HTML5 libs?

We are using sencha-touch. But we love to add in more libs if there is any lib that does this.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I'm 99.9% sure that's not a thing, sorry.  Browser searching occurs outside of the HTML/rendering world.

Comment: Yeah. It'd be pretty straightforward to build it in JS anyways.